# Mixing two arrays in one multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays and now I want to combine them as following example:

```
$prices    = array(100, 120, 135);
$discounts = array(5, 8, 15);
```

Mixed would leave:

```
$mixed_array = array(
    array('prices' => 100 , 'discount' => 5),
    array('prices' => 120 , 'discount' => 8),
    array('prices' => 135 , 'discount => 15)
);
```

Comment: The elements of two arrays is dynamic from database. What's function that mix them in multidimensional array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple example using a `foreach` loop on the prices, which captures the index or key in order to get the corresponding discount value.

```
$prices = array(100, 120, 135);
$discounts = array(5, 8, 15);
$mixed_array = array();

foreach($prices as $key => $price){
    $mixed_array[] = array(
        'prices' => $price,
        'discount' => $discounts[$key]
    );
}
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [prices] => 100
            [discount] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [prices] => 120
            [discount] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [prices] => 135
            [discount] => 15
        )

)
```